# SQL: Get Player Rank In Database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm building a high scores system for a game I'm building. I think or rather hope this is an easy question to answer. I need to get players "ranking" against other players. So let's say there are 3 players and your score is the lowest. So your rank would be #3. How do I get this in SQL? I think I use `COUNT` but I'm not sure how it's going to iterate through each row to find my player's score. I know I'll be doing an `ORDER BY`.

Here is my basic table:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Email]
  ,[High_Score]
  ,[Board_Name]
  ,[Difficulty]
  ,[Player_Time]
FROM [Rune_Master].[dbo].[High_Scores]
```

I'll need to **filter by** `Board_Name`, `Difficulty` because each board has 3 difficulties and the player could rank 3 different ways per board. Ultimately though it's based on their `High_Score` compared to others. There is only 1 score per player for each difficulty per board. So the scores will be unique by board + difficulty. I hope this all makes sense

This is what I have so far:

```
--Player Data
DECLARE @PlayerScore AS BIGINT
DECLARE @PlayerRank AS NVARCHAR(100)

IF EXISTS(SELECT [High_Score] FROM [dbo].[High_Scores] WHERE [Board_Name] = @Board AND [Difficulty] = @Difficulty AND [Email] = @Email) BEGIN
    SET @PlayerScore = (SELECT [High_Score] FROM [dbo].[High_Scores] WHERE [Board_Name] = @Board AND [Difficulty] = @Difficulty AND [Email] = @Email)
    SET @PlayerRank = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT([High_Score]) FROM [dbo].[High_Scores] WHERE [Board_Name] = @Board AND [Difficulty] = @Difficulty ORDER BY [High_Score] DESC)
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @PlayerScore = 0;
    SET @PlayerRank = 'UnRanked';
END

--Top 5 Player Scores
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5
    [High_Score] AS [Score],
    [Player_Time],
    [Board_Name],
    [Email],
    @PlayerScore AS 'Player_Score',
    @PlayerRank AS 'Player_Rank'
FROM
    [dbo].[High_Scores]
WHERE
    [Board_Name] = @Board AND
    [Difficulty] = @Difficulty
ORDER BY [High_Score] DESC, [Player_Time] DESC, [Email]
```

Comment: If Microsoft SQL Server (add relevant DB implementation as a tag!): `ROW_NUMBER() [or DENSE_RANK()] OVER (PARTITION BY.. [ORDER BY..])`.

Comment: Its MSSQL Express server but not sure I understand

Comment: eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Look up `Partition By`

Comment: ok So add this to a temp table and then select the value out of the temp table to get the persons rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer if anyone needs it. Thanks for your help btw everyone.

code:

```
    DECLARE
    @Board AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'Templo_Mayor',
    @Difficulty AS INT = 0,
    @Email AS NVARCHAR(500) = 'Computer',
    @PlayerRank AS NVARCHAR(100)


CREATE TABLE #Rank
(
    High_Score BIGINT,
    Row# BIGINT,
    EMAIL NVARCHAR(500)    
 )
INSERT INTO #Rank (High_Score, Row#, EMAIL) 
SELECT [High_Score], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [High_Score] DESC) AS Row#, [EMAIL] FROM [dbo].[High_Scores] WHERE [Board_Name] = @Board AND [Difficulty] = @Difficulty ORDER BY [High_Score] DESC

SELECT Row# FROM #Rank WHERE EMAIL = @Email ORDER BY [High_Score] DESC
DROP TABLE #Rank
```

So to explain what I did:

1. Declared my variables
2. Created a temp table I'm going to use to build my ranking table (temp table)
3. Populated my rank table with the data adding the rows counter
4. Selecting the rank of my user from my rank table by there email so I only get their rank returned.

Comment: Why do you need a temp table? All of this can be done in a single query. Use a CTE for the select statement that populates your temp table and then use that cte when selecting the final resultset. Don't get into the habit of applying this <select into, select> pattern for no reason. And one more thing - the use of DISTINCT should be very rare. If you think you need it, chances are you are covering up a logic flaw (or a poorly designed schema).

Comment: Feel free to share your answer. This works for now but I'd like to see what your suggesting to better understand.